# ROS: Access to sensor data from Jetson board

Tags: connection, usb, sensors, ros, nvidia-jetson

I dont know if someone can help me here. I also asked in the ros forum. So here is my problem:

Im working on a project and im a very beginner of ROS. I have a sensor which calculates the distance between two decanodes (range). The name of these two decanodes are AGV and SV. The AGV is the module which calculates the distance. Thats the key difference between AVG and SV. The AGV has to be connected to the PC via UART to USB, in my case its connected to the Jetson board. You have insight to the data of AGV with the docklight software. Its only for windows.
If everything is set up the sensor begins to collect the data (in meters).

My question is: How can I have access to these data. There is no information about that i should install a driver or something like that or a package. So if i connect it to the Jetson and if i look to the rosnode list i cant find anything which leads me to the data. I dont know what i have to do. I asked other people and they didnt know how to access the data if it is via UART to USB.
So it would be really nice if someone could write a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I think you will need to find documentation on the data format or protocol that your sensor is sending over its serial connection, or, if the manufacturer of the sensor provides a library or SDK with an API for receiving the data. Then write a new ROS node that receives the data and publishes it to the ROS system.

Comment: And what could i do if i cant find the documentation? And how can i publish a node to the ros system. Im sorry i think these are basic questions but im doing this for the first time. I know how to publish and subscribe (the basics) etc. But i never published something to the ros system

Comment: A node is not published to ROS. A node can publish a message containing data to ROS. Similarly, a node can subscribe and receive such published messages to get data from ROS. That you can find in ROS Wiki basic tutorials.

Comment: So if i have the sensor data i have to publish it as a message to a topic. But how do i know to which topic i have to publish. In my case i have message that gives me the range between two modules.

And the second question is: i got an answer on the ros forum and someone told me that i have to write a driver by my own. How can i do that? I couldt find a tutorial for this.